# Why is AVPlayer not continuing to next song while in background?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, ios9.3

I have been streaming music from remote source using AVPlayer. I get  URLs, use one to create an AVPlayerItem, which i then associate with my instance of AVPlayer. I add an observer to the item that I associate with the player to observe when the item finishes playing ( `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` ). When the observer notifies me at the item end, I then create a new AVPlayerItem and do it all over again. This works well in the foreground AND in the background on iOS 9.2.

**Problem:** Since I have updated to iOS 9.3 this does not work in the background. Here is the relevant code:

```
var portionToBurffer = Double()
var player = AVPlayer()


func prepareAudioPlayer(songNSURL: NSURL, portionOfSongToBuffer: Double){

   self.portionToBuffer = portionOfSongToBuffer

   //create AVPlayerItem
   let createdItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: songNSURL)

   //Associate createdItem with AVPlayer
   player = AVPlayer(playerItem: createdItem)

   //Add item end observer
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: player.currentItem)

   //Use KVO to see how much is loaded
   player.currentItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: .New, context: nil)

}


override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
if keyPath == "loadedTimeRanges" {
    if let loadedRangeAsNSValueArray = player.currentItem?.loadedTimeRanges {
        let loadedRangeAsCMTimeRange = loadedRangeAsNSValueArray[0].CMTimeRangeValue
        let endPointLoaded = CMTimeRangeGetEnd(loadedRangeAsCMTimeRange)
        let secondsLoaded = CMTimeGetSeconds(endPointLoaded)
        print("the endPointLoaded is \(secondsLoaded) and the duration is \(CMTimeGetSeconds((player.currentItem?.duration)!))")


        if secondsLoaded >= portionToBuffer  {
            player.currentItem?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges")
            player.play()
        }
    }
}
}



 func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification){
     recievedItemEndNotification()
 }





func recievedItemEndNotification() {
   //register background task
   bgTasker.registerBackgroundTask()

   if session.playlistSongIndex == session.playlistSongTitles.count-1 {
       session.playlistSongIndex = 0
   } else {
       session.playlistSongIndex += 1
   }

     prepareAudioPlayer(songURL: session.songURLs[session.playlistSongIndex], portionOfSongToBuffer: 30.00)

  }
```

I have set breakpoints to see that `player.play()` IS being called when in the background. When i print `player.rate` it reads `0.0`. I have checked the property `playbackLikelyToKeepUp` of the AVPlayerItem and it is `true`. I have confirmed also that the new URL is successfully used to create the new AVPlayerItem and associated with the AVPlayer when the app is in the background. I have turned audio and airplay background capabilities on and I have even opened up a finite length background task (in code above as `bgTasker.registerBackgroundTask`). No idea what is going on.

I found [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-9.0/) but i'm not sure it helps. Any advice would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the observer notifies me at the item end, I then create a new AVPlayerItem and do it all over again

But the problem is that meanwhile play stops, and the rule is that background playing is permitted only so long as you were playing in the foreground and continue to play in the background.

I would suggest using AVQueuePlayer instead of AVPlayer. This will allow you to enqueue the next item while the current item is still playing — and thus, we may hope, this will count as continuing to play.

Comment: So you think this is a change Apple made is iOS 9.3? Because the method I am using worked in earlier version, 9.1 and 9.2. Additionally, I have other operations in my code base that cause the player to pause, while in the background, load a new song, and then continue, and that works fine. It ONLY doesn't work when the item reaches the end of its duration and playback ceases in that way.

Comment: I have no idea. The change is news to me. I'm watching eagerly to see whether my queue player idea helps any.

Comment: Ok I will post as soon as I implement and test it out

Comment: Using AVQueuePlayer works. Thanks for the help as always @matt . I am still wondering why the code I was previously using just stopped working, do post something if you hear any news.

Comment: Interestingly, now with the AVQueuePlayer, that other operation in which the audio pauses while in the background and loads a new song then continues... does NOT work. Where as it was working with AVPlayer.

Comment: Ok I figured out how to solve all these issues. Simply adding the line `UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()` made it so that I was able to switch out AVPlayerItems while app was in background, and then resume playback.

Comment: In my case AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification is not playing next video if my app was in background state. Is it possible with UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents(). If yes can you please help me on where to use this.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the similar problem, and I searched lots of websites on google, but didn't find the answer.

### The Phenomenon

The problem of my app is that when I start play an audio, and turn the app to background, it will finish the playing of the current audio, and when playing the second audio, it will load some data, but then it stopped, if I turn the app to foreground, it will play the audio.

### Solution

My solution is to add the following call.

`UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()`

So enable background audio capabilities is not enough, we need to begin receiving remote controller events.